# How to ship a LEGO sculpture to a contest?

Tags: building, packaging, transport

I am planning to participate in an art contest that allows paintings, sculptures, or video clips. I have a LEGO sculpture in mind that would fit the idea of the contest, but it would have to be shipped to the jurors. The contest itself is not about LEGO at all, so I have no idea how they will react to a LEGO set. I just want to use it as a medium to convey my message.

The sculpture would be a diorama with a small figure (not a minifig) and some larger figures. The basic question is: How can the sculpture be delivered to the contest in one piece? I can think of some options:

1. **Glue**: Since the figures would stand in the diorama, the glueing area would be quite small, breaking is likely to happen.
2. **Sturdy build**, use Technic connections: Having the figures attached to the sculpture with lift arms would look weird and would probably decrease artistic value.
3. **Partly disassemble** the sculpture and give instructions for final assembly to the contest committee.

Number 3 is my favourite solution. However, is it acceptable for a contest to deliver a partly assembled sculpture?? I would wrap each figure separately and deliver also photographs/descriptions of the final arrangement.

Do you have experience with shipping sculptures and contests? What is the most feasible approach? Are there other considerations?

**EDIT:** After Mołot's comment I contacted the contest committee. They were very kind, and obviously, it is no problem to submit half-assembled work (in this case). Lesson learned: Ask!

Comment: *"is it acceptable for a contest to deliver a partly assembled sculpture?"* - No one here can know that. Only way to know that is to ask contest committee.

Comment: All 3 methods are necessary when shipping builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mołot commented, first ask the contest committee whether they have specific rules. In general though, shipping in chunks is common, ideally few pieces that are simple and straightforward to attach.

Rigid, sturdy builds are obviously going to stand up better to the travails of shipping, so try to avoid spindly construction. Follow good mechanical engineering principles, and if you can use technics for internal support, it may be very useful.

Glue also helps - yes, it's a bit more permanent, but for this type of production, you want that.

Additionally, shipping with "popcorn" pieces densely packed really helps prevent damage. Be aware that whoever unpacks it may be less keen :-)